# How Do I produce a specific number of Y Axis Tick Marks on a Scatterplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Below is my code, I just want the Y axis ticks to be in 5% increments, there are too many ticks, because they correspond to each plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = X, y = Y,  label = Label)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("steelblue4", "chartreuse4", "gold", "firebrick2")) +
  geom_text(aes(color = Goal), position = "jitter", hjust=0.5, vjust=1.1, size = 2.3) +
  labs(title = "Google", x = "Correlation Coefficient", y = "Top-Box %")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this layer to your ggplot:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(min(data$Y),max(data$Y),(max(data$Y)-min(data$Y))/20))
```

The `breaks=` argument takes a vector that allows you to manually specify the breaks. To get 20 equally spaced values from the lowest to highest values in `data$Y` the `seq` function comes in handy. You could also wrap the `seq()` function with `round()` function to clean up the potentially messy numbers that result from `max()-min()/20`.

Comment: I tried, I get "Error in Summary.factor(c(14L, 17L, 16L, 12L, 15L, 11L, 7L, 14L, 4L, 15L,  : min not meaningful for factors"

Comment: @user3638007 That's because your data Y is `factor` instead of `numeric`. If you convert `data$Y` to numeric (`data$Y=as.numeric(data$Y)`) and run the plot again it should work.

Comment: Yes, everything was fine when it was numeric, is there no way for me to keep the percentages and still have equal (and larger) increments?

Comment: @user3638007 I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your question. What exactly does your `data$Y` data look like? And what do you mean by "keep the percentages"?

Comment: Try adding `labels=percent` as an argument to the `scale_y_continuous` layer: `scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(min(data$Y),max(data$Y),(max(data$Y)-min(data$Y))/20),labels=percent)`. That should do the trick!

Comment: @user3638007 Did you try the percent formatting solution I mentioned above?